# Unity look at cursor in 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, cursor

I'm creating 2D game in Unity 3D, but I have problem with my player rotation.
It should rotate to the cursor, but when I start the game, its looking at Main camera.
I've tried lots of codes from lots of tutorials, but in most of it, my player is only looking to the center of Main camera.
This is my code now:

```
Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;

    Vector3 mouseWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3 (mouse.x, mouse.y, player.transform.position.y));

    Vector3 forward = mouseWorld - player.transform.position;
    player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (forward, Vector3.up);
```

Player is only looking to the camera. I'm not expert, but I think there is some problem with input, because some codes, that I've tried in past, did, that the player was only looking to nothing
(I'm not best in english... please apologize my mistakes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;

    Vector3 mouseWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3 (mouse.x, mouse.y,transform.position.z));

transform.right = mouseWorld -transform.position;
```

Comment: It's still looking on the camera :/

Comment: this code is for the player.
can  you take screenshot for me?

Comment: to the player is attached your script

Comment: This is in Update function

Comment: Can you debug mouse position on start?

Comment: Its normally changing, but the player is still on the same place

Comment: But "mouseWorld" is still (0.0, 1.0, -800.0)

Comment: you can edit code:

`Vector3 mouseWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
transform.right=new Vector2(mouseWorld.x,mouseWorld.y)- new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y);`

Comment: mouseWorld is still (0.0, 1.0, -800.0) :/

Comment: and it's looking to the center of camera (when i change camera position, player will change his rotation)

Comment: oh!. use my code. it will no longer use  mouseWorld.z. Because we are doing in 2D, we do not care about z.

Comment: It's looking to the center of main camera... again

Comment: When I delete "Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint" and set "mouseWorld" just to "Input.mousePosition", it starts to move with my cursor... but its really wierd moving

Comment: I've alredy solved it... it was in camera settings :D thanks for your time :)